# Update username as mail error with Asp.Identity

Tags: asp.net, email, identity

I have followed the same approach as teh0wner (in this post : [ASP.Net UserName to Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481835/asp-net-username-to-email/24084501#24084501) where the mail is recorded as the username which works weel so far) but when it's about updating the extra information of the user (phone number, date of birth,...) I encounter the following bug:

```
My update code:

    UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new          ApplicationDbContext());
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
    UserValidator<ApplicationUser> validator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager);
    var updateUser = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
        Id = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
        FirstName = FirstName.Text,
        MiddleName = MiddleName.Text,
        LastName = LastName.Text,
        Title = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList_Title.SelectedValue),
        BirthDate = DateOfBirth
    };

    var result = manager.UpdateAsync(updateUser);
    //IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(updateUser);

    store.Context.SaveChanges();

My model (IdentityModels.cs):


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Int32 Title { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
public class UserManager : UserManager
{
    public UserManager()
        : base(new UserStore(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        UserValidator = new UserValidator(this) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
    }
}
```

The error pops up at the updateAsync and mention that UserName can only be alphanumeric?!? What am I doing wrong? I don't get it, the username is already recorded as an email in the database

Comment: possible duplicate but try this 
`var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        ApplicationUser user =  userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;`
referenced from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448637/how-to-get-current-user-and-how-to-use-user-class-in-mvc5

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. The ".Result" was just missing.

```
 UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
 UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
 ApplicationUser user = manager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
```

...

```
var result = manager.UpdateAsync(user);
store.Context.SaveChanges();
```